# PWA in Safari with External Sign in provider

Tags: ios, safari, angular6, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA application, and the sign in is an external provider, like Auth0 and azure ad,
not handled inside angular,
the problem is when I open the application from Safari in any iPhone, it redirects me to the browser again,

in Google Chrome it is handling without any problems

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: please find the code here https://github.com/ahmadezzeir/angular6-connect-sample